# What is the purpose of this information in a seperate .yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm  pretty new to this and I was curious as to why this information may have been given to me in a separate .yml file to be used on a RoR app.
 I assumed that it was info to the put into my bash profile as it has corresponding environmental variables in the app itself.

BASE_URL: 'http://localhost.com:5000'

development:
  MAX_THREADS: '1'
  PORT: '5000'
  WEB_CONCURRENCY: '1'

test:

I'm also curious as to why you would want to set your url differently as the information states.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think changing the default port a matter of preference unless there's another part of the stack the development team likes to leave running at 3000 by default, for example, a Node.JS server or other projects.

The .yml file you've been given should be picked up when running `bundle exec <command>`, but not as part of your bash environment variables.